# template event class take any arg

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I have a simple event class, everything works fine with it.

Im trying to add a template class that i can pass arguments to and then read it when wait finishes.

At the moment i have it working with struct only as i need to set the arg to 0 if im not using it.

Is there a better/easier way to do this so i can pass any type of argument to it?

```
class Event
{
public:

    Event() : _signalled(false) {}

    virtual void notify()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        _signalled = true;
        _condvar.notify_one();
    }

    virtual void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        _condvar.wait(lock, [&] { return _signalled; });
        _signalled = false;
    }

    void stop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        _signalled = false;
    }

private:

    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _condvar;
    bool _signalled;
};

template <class T>
class ArgEvent : public Event
{
public:

    void notify()
    {
        Event::notify();
        this->arg = { 0 };
    }

    void notify(T arg)
    {
        Event::notify();
        this->arg = arg;
    }

    T getArg()
    {
        return this->arg;
    }

    void wait()
    {
        Event::wait();
    }

    void wait(T& arg)
    {
        Event::wait();
        arg = this->arg;
    }

private:
    T arg;
};
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik never seen that before, having problems setting thr T& arg in my wait function with this

Comment: ok i think i got it working, is there other ways to do this without c++17?

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Optional allows the implementation to work without c++17. 
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

Comment: dont like using extra libs